# Why mysql cannot join 2 big / large table?

Tags: mysql, join, loading

Here's my problem all :
I have 2 big table call it A n B.

If I join that's 2 table with a very simple query like this example :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lib_judul, lib_buku
```

Then mysql process is not over yet, I don't know why. Table A have 158,670 records (33,6 MB) and Table B have 130,028 records (34,6 MB). I think myquery is right, cause I've try before to join table A with table C (the very smaller table one) and it's run well.

What should I do to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You have implicit `CROSS JOIN` in your code which creates full [Cartesian Product](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm) of the two tables. It creates a new table with 158,670 times 130,028 rows. This is more than **20 billion** (20,631,542,760) records.

Answer (score 0):

It's because there is no common field for both of the tables. Try using `Explicit Join` just like below:

```
SELECT 
      COUNT(*) 
FROM lib_judul A 
JOIN lib_buku B ON A.id=B.id
```

Comment: Your statement (which could be correct) is not based on anything OP stated.

Comment: explicit join is like left join? is that performance better than join like in my example? thanks..... I need your suggest......

Answer (score 0):

The cost of your query maybe is too large. Your query have cost = 158,670 x 130,028 = 20,631,542,760 I/O.
The query execution plan will execute join first, then select the column.
Know your need. May be you can add some "where condition" before you join it. 
Example:
this query:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) 
FROM lib_judul A, lib_buku B 
WHERE B.id = 1 AND B.id = A.id
```

can be optimized like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM lib_judul) A 
  JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM lib_buku WHERE lib_buku.id = 1) B 
  ON B.id = A.id
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, but I think to get the lib_buku.id (on your example 1), I have to join it with another big table called table C. How if like this? thanks.....

Comment: Well that depend on how you get lib_buku.id. You can get it from sub-query to table C, or you can get it by join lib_buku with table C. If you need reference about join, here is the best tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp